# get percentage based on row having particular month success rate

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get percentage of "Success" in every month in excel.
I tried to get month and year but couldnt collective get row values with same month

Jan : 33.3% [ (100/no. of records in month) + (count of "Success" in that month)]

Feb : 100%

Can we do any sql like query to get percentage? I am not sure what to do

[image]

Comment: Are you able to add a helper column?

Comment: not sure follow the math. jan had 9 failures and 1 success which results in 33% ? Feb is understandable 100% = 12 successes with no fails.

Comment: @bvaughn The numbers are not relevant, just the status column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `COUNTIFS` formula and some helper columns.

[image: Excel screenshot]

The formula in K2 is:

```
=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$6,"="&MONTH(I2),G$2:G$6,"Success")/COUNTIF(B$2:B$6,"="&MONTH(I2))
```

formatted to appear as a percentage.

The helper column B is simply converting the month to a number, for example for cell B2:

```
=MONTH(A2)
```

You can hide this column if preferred.

Column I is a date (e.g. 01-Jan) formatted to appear with month only (`mmm`).